# How to add a new property in json structure existing in nvarchar(max) type column in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have data like this in an `employee` table in a column of type `nvarchar(max)`:

```
{
   "ID":101,
   "FirstName":"Vatan",
   "LastName":"Soni"
}
```

Now I need to update all rows with `FullName` property as well, so result should be

```
{
    "ID":101,
    "FirstName":"Vatan",
    "LastName":"Soni",
    "FullName":"Vatan Soni"
}
```

Please help and provide the SQL update script for it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Starting with SQL 2016 you have JSON types and functions: [`JSON_MODIFY`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/json-modify-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

```
UPDATE <table> 
  SET <column> = JSON_MODIFY(<column>, '$.FullName', 
  JSON_VALUE(<column>, '$.FirstName') + ' ' + JSON_VALUE(<column>, '$.LastName'))
```

Comment: Its like 

Company ID EmployeeData
501                 { "ID":101, "FirstName":"Vatan", "LastName":"Soni" }
501                 { "ID":102, "FirstName":"Ratan", "LastName":"Jain" }
502                 { "ID":103, "FirstName":"Patan", "LastName":"Sharma" }